# How can I access my home router after connecting to my home VPN?

Tags: networking, router, vpn

I used SoftEther to set up a VPN server at home and I would like to access the router admin page after I have connected to my VPN server. Normally it is 192.168.0.1, but that doesn't work. I *thought* after I connected to my home VPN then I would have access to everything in the LAN network as if I was connected to the router directly.

How can I do this?

Bonus: Please clarify my understanding of a VPN network--I obviously don't understand how it works.

EDIT: Result of `Route Print`

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10586]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>route print
===========================================================================
Interface List
 10...00 ac db 25 09 63 ......VPN Client Adapter - VPN
  7...34 02 86 44 39 a6 ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
  8...34 02 86 44 39 a5 ......Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265
 12...34 02 86 44 39 a9 ......Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
  4...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
  6...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
  5...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0        10.20.0.1     10.20.91.211     25
        10.20.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link      10.20.91.211    281
     10.20.91.211  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.20.91.211    281
    10.20.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.20.91.211    281
   99.235.232.235  255.255.255.255        10.20.0.1     10.20.91.211     25
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
       129.97.2.1  255.255.255.255        10.20.0.1     10.20.91.211     25
    130.158.6.116  255.255.255.255        10.20.0.1     10.20.91.211     25
      169.254.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link    169.254.40.251    257
   169.254.40.251  255.255.255.255         On-link    169.254.40.251    257
  169.254.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    169.254.40.251    257
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    169.254.40.251    257
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      10.20.91.211    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    169.254.40.251    257
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.20.91.211    281
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  8    281 ::/0                     fe80::7ead:74ff:fe1f:8e00
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
  8    281 2620:101:f000:700::/64   On-link
  8    281 2620:101:f000:700:599b:1d24:f55c:fe90/128
                                    On-link
  8    281 2620:101:f000:700:f464:fc0f:b03c:1489/128
                                    On-link
 10    276 fe80::/64                On-link
  8    281 fe80::/64                On-link
  8    281 fe80::599b:1d24:f55c:fe90/128
                                    On-link
 10    276 fe80::a014:581a:2487:28fb/128
                                    On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 10    276 ff00::/8                 On-link
  8    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Comment: Is the local network you are physically connected to using the 192.168.0.0/24 network as well? if so, disable split tunneling. after you VPN in, do you get a valid IP on your home network? can you ping systems on the lan? can you ping the router? if you run `route print` while connected, is there a route to 192.168.0.0/24 that exits from your VPN virtual network adapter? Also, is this a home or enterprise grade router? many fancy routers have special firewall rulesets for VPN.

Comment: I will look into more detail when I go back to school. I was trying to do this from my campus internet service to my home computer (where I have the VPN). When I tried the address, it took a while to load and then it timed out repeatedly. This is a CGN3 Rogers router. I'll get back to you once I can run the route print at school.

Comment: Ok, I've looked a little bit at softether. What VPN protocols are you using (ie SSL, L2TP/IPSEC, MS-SSTP, etc)? Have you confirmed that the home router allows the ports for the protocol you selected above in the Firewall incoming ruleset?